# Синхронизация темы сайта и мобильного устройства

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сейчас довольна популярна тёмная тема. И, например, если поставить её на телефоне в настройках, то в большинстве приложений (Instagram, Telegram, Viber, Facebook и тд.) она адаптируется, то есть на них тоже включается тёмная тема. Как сделать тоже самое на сайте, там тоже есть переключение светлой / тёмной темы.

Comment: Под приложениями вы понимаете приложения под Android или оси  Apple?

Comment: 1. https://css-tricks.com/a-complete-guide-to-dark-mode-on-the-web/#using-a-body-class
2. https://blog.sethcorker.com/automatic-dark-mode-for-your-website